# Displaying an image via acf in the theme header

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using AFC Pro and created an options pafe so tjhat the user can upload a new header logo whenever he wants to.

The ACF field is called "headerlogo".

What I want now is that the Logo gets replaced by my theme automatically.

My Variables are:

```
$headerlogo = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('headerlogo', 'option'), 'full');

$default_logo = '<img src="'echo .$headerlogo[0].'" alt="SITE Logo">';
```

they get called in:

```
echo '<a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">
            ' . $default_logo . '
        </a>';
```

But the Output is:

```
<a href="http://www.xxx.de/">
                <img src="" alt="SITELogo">
            </a>
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
$headerlogo = get_field('headerlogo');
if( !empty($headerlogo) ):
    $default_logo = '<img src="'. $headerlogo['url'] . '" alt="' . $headerlogo['alt'] . '" />';
endif;


echo '<a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">' . $default_logo . '</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Almost, but you got me there ;
ACF Options require a $post_id parameter 'options'.
So the full var is:
$headerlogo = get_field('headerlogo', 'options');

But other than that I got it working with you code.
Thank you!